# Select all checkbox to be checked if all checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jsp, checkbox

I need my `selectAll` checkbox to be checked if all the other checkboxes are checked.
Any idea how to do this in javascript?

My javascript code:

```
function selectAll(box) {
    var selectAllchk = box.checked;
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('chkbox');
    if (box.checked){
        for (var i in checkboxes){
            $(":checkbox").attr("checked", true);
        }
    } else {
        $('input:checkbox:not(:disabled)').removeAttr('checked');
    }
}


function selectCheckAll(box){
    var a = ('.checkbox').length;
    if ($(':checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length) {
       //do something
    }
};
```

Jsp code:

```
<td align="center" colspan="5">
  <display:table name="contratBonusForm" property="contrats" defaultsort="1" 
  sort="list" defaultorder="ascending" requestURI="/gestionContratBonusActionIn.do?dispatch=searchContrat" 
  uid="current" pagesize="30" class="tableauDisplayTag">
   <display:column title="ID Type" property="id" sortable="true"/>
   <display:column title="Type de contrat" property="type" sortable="true"/>
  <% %>
  <display:column title="Bonus <input type='checkbox' name='selectall' onClick='selectAll(this)'/>" align="center" >
  <% TypeContratPOJO type = (TypeContratPOJO) pageContext.getAttribute("current");
  Long Eli = 1L;
  int ok = type.getBonus().compareTo(Eli);
  (current != null &&  ok == 0) { %>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" checked="checked" onClick='selectCheckAll(this)' value="<%=indice%>"/>
  <% } else { %>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="<%=indice%>"/>
  <% } %>
  </display:column>
  <%indice++; %>            
  </display:table>
</td>
```

When I select a checkbox it does not enter the selectCheckAll function.

Comment: Do some basic debugging. **Look at your HTML**. You have some JSP: What HTML does it generate? Is the problem that it doesn't generate the HTML that you want or is it that the HTML you want doesn't have the effect you want? Don't just look at the JS and the server side code. Narrow the problem down.

Comment: Open the Console in your browser's developer tools. Are any errors shown? What about when you click on the checkbox?

Comment: `for (var i in checkboxes){$(":checkbox").attr("checked", true);}` likely doesn't do much.

Comment: @RobG : the selectAll function works properly.  What I want to do is the selectAll checkbox to be checked if all the other ones are checked.

Comment: It would be much better if you post HTML rather than JSP. It seems you just need to compare the number that are checked vs the total number that might be checked, or just see if at least one is not checked. What is the selector for the set that "select all" applies to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the number that can be checked vs the number that are checked and set the check all checkbox accordingly. The following is a quick hack in POJS to demonstrate the method, there's likely a jQuery equivalent.

```js
function checkAll(inp) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.groupA').forEach(el => el.checked = inp.checked);
}

function setCheckAll() {
  document.querySelector('input.checkAll').checked =
     document.querySelectorAll('.groupA').length ==
     document.querySelectorAll('.groupA:checked').length;
}
```

```html
A <input class="groupA" type="checkbox" checked onclick="setCheckAll()"><br>
B <input class="groupA" type="checkbox" onclick="setCheckAll()"><br>
Check all<input class="checkAll" type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)">
```

Comment: Can I use the setCheckAll function so that this check is done when the page is being loaded  in jsp?

Comment: @user3762810—I expect you'll re–write the function using jQuery. You can run it anytime, but I'd also expect the checkboxes to be loaded with an appropriate *checked* value so it only needs to run in response to user actions.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to bind a change event to your check box then check it.
I don't know if there is any other better way, but I'd do it in this way, please tell me if there are any other better ways. Thanks

```
var myChkBoxes = $('.checkbox')
myChkBoxes .on('change', function(){
  var blnAllChk = $('.checkbox:checked').length === myChkBoxes.length;
  blnAllChk ? (all checkboxes are checked, do something) : (else, do something);
});
```