# Checked all checkbox when header cell is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

I need for **all checkbox** to be checked or unchecked when either **header cell** (yellow color) or **checkbox in header cell** is clicked.

```js
  $('th, td').click(function (event) {
 
if (!$(event.target).is('input')) {

    $('input:checkbox', this).prop('checked', function (i, value) {
     
        //console.log('i', i)
      //console.log('value', value)
      //console.log('this', this)
      
      //$(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked); // disable this line for working checkedbox when cell is clicked.
      //$(':checkbox[class="check_all"]').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
      
       return !value;
     });
  }
  });
```

```html
<style>
  th, td {border:1px solid black;padding:20px;}
</style>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>Header. Nothing should happen will click cell in this column</th>
    <th bgcolor= "yellow"><input id="header" type="checkbox"/></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><input class="check_all" type="checkbox"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td><input class="check_all" type="checkbox"/></td>
</tr>    
</table>
```

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ockr05d9/

Please assist me.

Comment: What exactly is the expected behavior? Please elaborate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement "select all" check box in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386281/how-to-implement-select-all-check-box-in-html)

Comment: @Unmitigated I need for all checkbox to be checked or unchecked when either header cell (yellow color box) or checkbox in header cell (yellow color box) is clicked.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I actually have working code when checked box in header cell is clicked. What I need now is when `header cell` is clicked, all checkbox will be checked or unchecked.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, there are many duplicates for that scenario as well: [if some checkboxes are 'checked' then check all javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61818723/215552), [How to check if all checkboxes are unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14800954/215552), [Select all checkbox to be checked if all checkboxes are checked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45540344/215552)...

Answer (score 0):

- Use `data-*` attribute on your checkbox to assign each to a specific *family*, namely: `data-toggle-family` for the *"head parent"* checkbox and `data-family` for the associated checkboxes
- If needed, for a better UI,UX use the [`indeterminate` state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:indeterminate) for the *"parent head checkbox"* ([read more in this CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/) where examples cover use-cases for tree structure)

Example:

```js
// Parent
$("[data-toggle-family]").on("input", function() {
  const family = $(this).data("toggle-family");
  const $children = $(`[data-family="${family}"]`);
  $children.prop({
    checked: this.checked
  });
});

// Related children
$("[data-family]").on("input", function() {
  const family = $(this).data("family");
  const $parent = $(`[data-toggle-family="${family}"]`);
  const $siblings = $(`[data-family="${family}"]`);
  const $siblingsCkd = $siblings.filter(":checked");
  const allChecked = $siblingsCkd.length === $siblings.length;
  const allUnchecked = $siblingsCkd.length === 0;
  $parent.prop({
    checked: allChecked,
    indeterminate: !allChecked && !allUnchecked
  });
});

// Addon: Make entire parent row clickable
$("tr:has([data-toggle-family])").on("click", function(evt) {
  const $parent = $(this).find("[data-toggle-family]");
  if ($(evt.target).is($parent)) return;
  $parent.prop("checked", !$parent.prop("checked"));
  $parent.trigger("input");
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th><input data-toggle-family="one" type="checkbox"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td><input data-family="one" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td><input data-family="one" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th><input data-toggle-family="two" type="checkbox"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td><input data-family="two" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td><input data-family="two" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td><input data-family="two" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

PS:
Not needed for the JS part to work, but remember to assign `name="someName"` attribute to your children input elements. If you want you can also rewrite the above to work in relation to that `name` attribute:

```html
<input data-toggle-family="one" type="checkbox">
<input name="one" type="checkbox">
<input name="one" type="checkbox">
<input data-toggle-family="two" type="checkbox">
<input name="two" type="checkbox">
<input name="two" type="checkbox">
```

Not needed for this example, but it's useful to always explicitly use the `tbody` element. The browser will create it regardless. You can also create more than one TBODY if needed. Also, you can use the `th` element for a better markup syntax — where needed.

### Pure JavaScript solution

Nowadays jQuery is not necessary. Here's a remake in JavaScript without any external library:

```js
// DOM utils:
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);

// Parent
els("[data-toggle-family]").forEach(elParent => {
  elParent.addEventListener("input", () => {
    const family = elParent.dataset.toggleFamily;
    const elsChildren = els(`[data-family="${family}"]`);
    elsChildren.forEach(elChild => elChild.checked = elParent.checked);
  });
});

// Related children
els("[data-family]").forEach(elChild => {
  elChild.addEventListener("input", () => {
    const family = elChild.dataset.family;
    const elParent = el(`[data-toggle-family="${family}"]`);
    const elsSiblings = els(`[data-family="${family}"]`);
    const siblingsCkd = [...elsSiblings].filter(el => el.checked);
    const allChecked = siblingsCkd.length === elsSiblings.length;
    const allUnchecked = siblingsCkd.length === 0;
    elParent.checked = allChecked;
    elParent.indeterminate = !allChecked && !allUnchecked;
  });
});

// Addon: Make entire parent row clickable
els("tr:has([data-toggle-family])").forEach(elTr => {
  elTr.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    if (evt.target.closest(`[data-toggle-family]`)) return
    const elParent = el(`[data-toggle-family]`, elTr);
    console.log(111)
    elParent.checked = !elParent.checked;
    elParent.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", {bubbles: true}));
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th><input data-toggle-family="one" type="checkbox"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td><input data-family="one" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td><input data-family="one" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th><input data-toggle-family="two" type="checkbox"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td><input data-family="two" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td><input data-family="two" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td><input data-family="two" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I actually have working code when checked box in header cell is clicked. What I need now is when `header cell` is clicked (area around the header checkbox), all checkbox will be checked or unchecked.

Comment: @sg552 The simplest is to use a `<label for="family-one">Header 1</label>`, make is CSS `display: block;`, and use `<input id="family-one" data-toggle-family="one" type="checkbox">` for the family checkbox.

Comment: Or by using jQuery: I'll edit the examples above for this ones.